# A java driver from c

Tags: java

I am trying to wrap a driver for a DB with a Java API. I am able to call the driver through JNI. Though this was a big task for me, I now understand that this is just the beginning. What are the other testing that I need to do to make sure my Java driver works correctly? I am testing the character encoding and some data type conversions. But is there anything I have to test that I do not do.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... really seems a big task!

Although many tasks already was developed by original code, I think you will need tons of tests, possible areas could be:

- Multithreading: You need test if your wrapper will support multiple database connections open. Put special attention in synchronised blocks of code, static fields modification, isolation of session
- Type conversion: You will need ensure that expected C types were correctly converted to Java primitives and classes. This issue is important, you must check all types
- Error management: Test correct transform between C errors and Java exception

Sure, I missed many areas.

Comment: Thanks , expecting a few more answers